# Error on modal of bootstrap, doesnt work the button of "save". Laravel 5.8 BootStrap 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I am creating the modals of my project in Laravel. I already got the modal to work when clicking to delete. What happens is that when I click on "save changes", to finish deleting, it does nothing.  Absolutely nothing happens. 
I would like to know what is happening, because I really do not know, I had never worked with modals before.

This is what the buttons of my view are, without the modal they work perfectly, they edit and delete, in fact I only care about the modal in eliminating, that I managed to eliminate when clicking.

```
<td>
                   <a href="empleados/edit/{{$key->id}}" style="width: 60%;" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                   <form action="empleados/{{$key->id}}" method="POST" class="">
                               @method('DELETE')
                               @csrf
                               <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" value="submit" style="width: 60%;" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>



                   </form>
                 </td>
```

This is what is in my view, the modal as such.

```
 <div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="delete">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
              </div>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                <p>¿Esta seguro de eliminar este empleado?&hellip;</p>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
                <button type="button" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-outline">Eliminar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a modal, you've got to have something to handle the action from the button.  You could make it a link and send to a controller which will handle the delete and then redirect to a new page.

Or, more typically, a button would have some type of **javascript** or **AJAX** method to take the `id` of the item you wish to delete, and send this asynchronously to the server.  The controller on the server would delete the item and then send back a success message to your **AJAX** method on the blade page.

An example of an **AJAX** method within a **Laravel blade** page might be similar to:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#elminar', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('yourDeleteURL')}}/" + id,
                type: "DELETE",
                data: {
                    _method: 'DELETE'
                },
                success: function () {
                    // Optional to delete the item without refreshing the page
                    $("#item" + id).remove(); 
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```